# How to incorporate variable in R Markdown slide title

Tags: variables, r-markdown, slide

I am using R Markdown to create slides.   At the top of a slide I want to title it
"For threshold 3%" (example).

I want to specify this like:

"For threshold (followed by a variable name whose value is 3) followed by '%'" sign.

I thought if I could do it by saying

"For threshold $threshold"

or

"For threshold {'threshold'}" etc.

but it doesn't seem to work!

So, how can I do this?  I don't see any examples where the slide title is referencing a variable whose value has to appear in the actual slide.

Comment: read this doc before post your query :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I read that.  My question still stands.  I have modified it a little to add clarity.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inline code](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html):

```
## For threshold `r myvar`%

My slide's text
```

Obviously, `myvar` needs to be defined before the slide's title.

Comment: Thank you very much!   That worked like I wanted it to.